# React Bootstrap carousel not sliding correctly, goes blank before transition

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

This is my code

Every time it slides to the next image, the transition makes the image disappear, and then it goes to the next one, I'm using react-bootstrap 5.1.0 but it seems like something is not working correctly.

I tried with the styles, but it seems like it's not working

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Y5O.jpg)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

```
export default class CarouselPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Carousel>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/1440x500"
                        alt="First slide"
                    />
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>First slide label</h3>
                        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/1440x500"
                        alt="Second slide"
                    />

                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/1440x500"
                        alt="Third slide"
                    />

                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing this code works fine.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

this code is needed in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Ahh I am getting the same strange behaviour, I will test this! Thanks

Comment: Alright, I don't get why it works, can you explain? [In the doc they do say to include as link 4 lines of code with rel/href/integrity/crossorigin](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#css)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using the `bootstrap` class utility by directly calling the class as with the docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/. The sliding animation for the carousel seems to not work until I added this line `import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"`, along with `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. These lines could be added in the root `index.js` file or in the individual files respectively.